# What is the correct Provider<AuthBlock> for my DrawerNavigation Widget?

Tags: flutter, android-contentprovider, google-signin

I am working on a simple mobile app with Google sign in capabilities.

So far, the app has been working, but with the latest step (the actual signing in) I am receiving the following error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<AuthBlock> above this DrawerNavigation Widget
```

I have tried the usual suspects; ensuring that the right packages are being imported, that it is due to me running on a virtual mobile device, and that a hot reboot might have been needed.
The issue persists however.

I had expected it to prompt the user to sign in with Google, but that is obviously not happening.

My code is as follows, and I believe the error is originating from line 54 which reads **final authBlock = Provider.of(context);**.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/blocks/auth_block.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/screens/categories_screen.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/screens/todos_by_category.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/service/category_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';

class DrawerNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerNavigationState createState() => _DrawerNavigationState();
}

class _DrawerNavigationState extends State<DrawerNavigation> {
  //List<Widget> _categoryList = List<Widget>(); //Has been depricated
  List<Widget> _categoryList = List<Widget>.generate(0, (index) {
    //Widget obj = Widget();
    //obj.id = index;
    return;
  });

  CategoryService _categoryService = CategoryService();

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllCategories();
  }

  getAllCategories() async {
    var categories = await _categoryService.readCategories();

    categories.forEach((category) {
      setState(() {
        _categoryList.add(InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new TodosByCategory(
                        category: category['name'],
                      ))),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(category['name']),
          ),
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authBlock = Provider.of<AuthBlock>(context);
    return Container(
      child: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            // UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            //   currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
            //       backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
            //           'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1733/6579/products/product-image-602960373_1024x1024@2x.jpg')),
            //   accountName: Text('Meena Bobeena'),
            //   accountEmail: Text('meena@happycat.com'),
            //   decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            // ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SignInButton(
                  Buttons.Google,
                  onPressed: () => authBlock.loginWithGoogle(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.home),
              title: Text('Home'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => (HomeScreen()))),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.view_list),
              title: Text('Categories'),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => (CategoriesScreen()))),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Column(
              children: _categoryList,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As requested, the following is how the DrawerNavigation is called.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/helpers/drawer_navigation.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/screens/todo_screen.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/service/todo_service.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/models/todo.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  TodoService _todoService;

  //List<Todo> _todoList = List<Todo>(); // Has been deprecated
  List<Todo> _todoList = List<Todo>.generate(0, (index) {
    Todo obj = Todo();
    obj.id = index;
    return obj;
  });

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllTodos();
  }

  getAllTodos() async {
    _todoService = TodoService();
    //_todoList = List<Todo>(); //Has been depricated
    _todoList = List<Todo>.generate(0, (index) {
      Todo obj = Todo();
      obj.id = index;
      return obj;
    });

    var todos = await _todoService.readTodos();

    todos.forEach((todo) {
      setState(() {
        var model = Todo();
        model.id = todo['id'];
        model.title = todo['title'];
        model.description = todo['description'];
        model.category = todo['category'];
        model.todoDate = todo['todoDate'];
        model.isFinished = todo['isFinished'];
        _todoList.add(model);
      });
    });
  }

  _deleteFormDialog(BuildContext context, categoryId) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (param) {
          return AlertDialog(
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Cancel'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
                // This doesn't delete :'(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var result = await _todoService.deleteTodos(categoryId);
                  //print(result);
                  if (result > 0) {
                    print(result);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    getAllTodos();
                    _showSuccessSnackBar(Text('Deleted'));
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Delete'),
              ),
            ],
            title: Text('Are you sure you wish to delete this To Do item ?'),
          );
        });
  }

  _showSuccessSnackBar(message) {
    var _snackBar = SnackBar(content: message);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(_snackBar);
    //_globalKey.currentState.showSnackBar(_snackBar); === Depreciated
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Meenas To Do List')),
      drawer: DrawerNavigation(),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _todoList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 8,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(_todoList[index].title ?? 'No Title'),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _deleteFormDialog(context, _todoList[index].id);
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(_todoList[index].category ?? 'No Category'),
                  trailing: Text(_todoList[index].todoDate ?? 'No Date'),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TodoScreen())),
          child: Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code where I instantiate the provider

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/service/auth_service.dart';

class AuthBlock {
  final authService = AuthService();
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);

  Stream<User> get currentUser => authService.currentUser;

  loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      );

      //Firebase Sign In
      final result = await authService.signInWithCredential(credential);

      print('${result.user.displayName}');
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  logout() {
    authService.logout();
  }
}
```

The main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_do_list/src/app.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your app with the provider? E.g. like you see [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example)

```
runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I had tried that too, but with no luck.

I tried following this tutorial, and implementing things a bit differently, but they still have not helped. I have copied the time stamp for the end of the implementation too, in case that helps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uYO2ht5Nl4&t=2061s

Comment: Can you also add the code where you instantiate the provider and how you call the DrawerNavigation widget to your question?

Comment: Great, one last thing is the code where you call your app. Like runApp(ToDoListApp())

Comment: Added that last little bit too. Thanks

Comment: Where do you call the following?
Provider(
  create: (_) => AuthBlock(),
  child: App()
)

Comment: I am not calling that anywhere that I can tell, as the tutorial has indicated that it was not needing to be called. It functions in the tutorial without being called.

You'll have to forgive my nativity as this is my first attempt at working with Google Sign In.

Comment: At https://youtu.be/_uYO2ht5Nl4?t=1880 he wraps the app with an instance of the provider. I'm pretty sure you'll have to do this as well, at least that's how I would interprete you'r error message. Please try that and tell me if it worked.